# How can we use HTTP_INTERCEPTORS to call refresh token, whenever it gets expired

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

**My Objective**:While sending the request I pass the token key in header to validate the API request. If the token is expired, I will call new token and again send the request with new token to get the response.

**My error**:I am getting the below error

```
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

**My Code:**

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
const authToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token')
if(authToken){
  /**
   * Modifying the request to add the token in request header
   */
  const reqClone = request.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: authToken
    }
  });
  return next.handle(reqClone).pipe(
    catchError(reason => {
      if(reason.error != undefined && reason.error.code == "TOKEN_EXPIRED"){
        this.reCallWithNewToken(request,reason,next);
      }else{
        return throwError(reason);
      }

    })
  )
}

reCallWithNewToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, error: any ,next: HttpHandler){
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
  if (user) {
    user.getIdToken(true)
      .then(token => {
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
        const reqCloneNewToken = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: token
          }
        });
        console.info("API Request with new token: ", reqCloneNewToken);
        return next.handle(reqCloneNewToken);
      });
    }else{
      return throwError(error);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: The callback passed to catchError() is supposed to return an Observable. But it doesn't. It just calls `this.reCallWithNewToken(request,reason,next);`. And even with an added `return`, it still ouldn't return anything since `reCallWithNewToken()` doesn't return an observable. Instead, it subscribes to an observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Thanks to @JBNizet.
I am posting my code if anyone get the same issue.

I modified my function `reCallWithNewToken` to

```
reCallWithNewToken() {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
        if (user) {
          user.getIdToken(true)
            .then(token => {
              localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
              observer.next(token);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              observer.error(error);
            });
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

And then inside `catchError`

```
if (reason.error != undefined && reason.error.code == "TOKEN_EXPIRED") {
   return this.reCallWithNewToken().pipe(
      switchMap(()=>next.handle(this.addAuthHeader(request)))
   )
}
```